# How long does mongo_connector.py usually take?

Tags: mongodb, solr, pymongo

I am trying to update a Solr index from MongoDB. The issue is that it seems to take forever to run and I can't determine whether it is timing out. I can leave it for up to 6 hours at a time and don't see anything happening. I'm beginning to suspect I'm doing something wrong. The data is about 2Gb. So I'm wondering if anyone has a similar experience on using mongo_connector.py on a similar, or larger amount of data, then any point in the right direction would be great.

The server I'm trying this on is Ubuntu 12.04.

The line I'm using to invoke mongo_connector.py is:

```
python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo-connector/mongo_connector.py --oplog-ts /var/log/oplog.log -m 127.0.0.1:27017 -t http://localhost:8080/solr4
```

The output is as follows:

```
2012-08-19 19:24:57,950 - INFO - Beginning Mongo Connector
2012-08-19 19:24:57,951 - INFO - No doc manager specified, using simulator.
2012-08-19 19:24:58,956 - INFO - OplogManager: Initializing oplog thread
2012-08-19 19:24:58,958 - INFO - MongoConnector: Starting connection thread Connection('127.0.0.1', 27017)
```

Any insights or help from someone who has used mongo_connector.py successfully would be helpful, even if you think you're only telling me something trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a doc manager, it isn't doing anything yet. It seems the connection is working so you should look at the following additional options to set paying specific attention to `-d` or `--docManager` as that is what the output says is missing from your current configuration. This might work (i've removed the backslashes and simply shown this on multiple lines for convenience)

```
python mongo_connector.py
  --oplog-ts /var/log/oplog.log
  -m 127.0.0.1:27017
  -d /doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py
  -t http://localhost:8080/solr4
```

## Mongo Connector Options

To start the system, simply run "python mongo_connector.py". It is likely, however, that you will need to specify some command line options to work with your setup. They are described below:

`-m` or `--mongos` is to specify the main address, which is a host:port pair. For sharded clusters, this should be the mongos address. For individual replica sets, supply the address of the primary. For example, `-m localhost:27217` would be a valid argument to -m. Don't use quotes around the address.

`-t` or `--target-url` is to specify the URL to the target system being used. For example, if you were using Solr out of the box, you could use `-t http://localhost:8080/solr` with the SolrDocManager to establish a proper connection. Don't use quotes around address. If target system doesn't need URL, don't specify.

`-o` or `--oplog-ts` is to specify the name of the file that stores the oplog progress timestamps. This file is used by the system to store the last timestamp read on a specific oplog. This allows for quick recovery from failure. By default this is config.txt, which starts off empty. An empty file causes the system to go through all the mongo oplog and sync all the documents. Whenever the cluster is restarted, it is essential that the oplog-timestamp config file be emptied - otherwise the connector will miss some documents and behave incorrectly.

`-n` or `--namespace-set` is used to specify the namespaces we want to consider. For example, if we wished to store all documents from the test.test and alpha.foo namespaces, we could use -n test.test,alpha.foo. The default is to consider all the namespaces, excluding the system and config databases, and also ignoring the "system.indexes" collection in any database.

`-u` or `--unique-key` is used to specify the mongoDB field that will serve as the unique key for the target system. The default is "_id", which can be noted by "-u _id"

`-f` is to specify a file which contains the password for authentication. This file is used by mongos to authenticate connections to the shards, and we'll use it in the oplog threads. The main use of this option is to specify a password without entering it as plaintext on the command line.

`-p` is to specify the password used for authentication. If this option is specified along with -f, then the password specified here will be used regardless of the contents of the password file. For sharded clusters, the admin username/password must exist in every shard's admin database, otherwise the system will fail to authenticate. This is because of how the connector authenticates against the shards, which is described in depth in the System Internals section below.

`-a` or `--admin-username` is used to specify the username of an admin user to authenticate with. To use authentication with the system, the user must specify both this option and the password or password file option, which stores the password for the user. The default username is '__system', which is not recommended for production use. If using this and one of the password options in a sharded environment, it is essential that the username/password exists in the admin database of every shard in the cluster. Otherwise, authentication will fail.

`-d` or `--docManager` is used to specify the doc manager file that is going to be used. You should send the path of the file you want to be used. By default, it will use the doc_manager_simulator.py file. It is recommended that all doc manager files be kept in the doc_managers folder in mongo-connector. For more information about making your own doc manager, see Doc Manager section.

## Additional Info

Since the connector does real time syncing, it is necessary to have MongoDB running a replica set setup. I'm going to assume that is the case and you just need a doc manager as it says.

See [this](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/blob/master/mongo-connector/README.md) url for more information

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That works. However, now I am getting the next error: "2012-08-20 03:46:02,981 - ERROR - [Reason: /solr4/update/]" ... Currently trying to figure it out.

Comment: May I have a replica set setup but with only one primary (without secondaries, or, in other words, a replica set setup with only one instance)? Does it make sense to use mongo-connector?